# Want to pull out specific objects inside array

Tags: mongodb

I have a data structure like this, I want to pull out "userNames" with "isUserFixed" 0 from users array.

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5b8e7fda725bec7b317b94f6"),
   "email" : "test@test.com",
   "users" : [ 
       {
           "userName" : "user1",
           "isUserFixed" : 0
       }, 
       {
           "userName" : "user2",
           "isUserFixed" : 0
       }, 
       {
           "userName" : "user3",
           "isUserFixed" : 0
       }, 
       {
           "userName" : "user4",
           "isUserFixed" : 0
       }, 
       {
           "userName" : "user5",
           "isUserFixed" : 0
       }
   ]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What programming language / framework are you using?

Comment: Do you need this as a 'find' query, or an update?

Comment: If you know the from which index you need to pick an object from the array, you can do that. As you have same object key in each array index. How will you want to achieve it?

Comment: I am using express and node js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
db.getCollection('').aggregate([{"$match": {"Your match criteria key": "Your match criteria value"}},
    {"$group" : {"_id" : {"email": "$email"}}},        
    {
                "$project": {
                    "users": {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$users",
                            "as": "user",
                            "cond": {
                                "$in": ["$$user.isUserFixed", [0]]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        ])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer